# How to get accurately callback when FaceID animation finished?

Tags: ios, face-id

successBlock executes before FaceID animation finished

```
[self.LAContent evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"tip" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (success) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (successBlock) {
                successBlock();
            }
        });
    }
    if (error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    }
}];
```

Comment: that is ok, you should react as fast as possible, why do you want to delay callback?

Comment: the successBlock has been already executed before the animation finished. 
It should be  executed after the animation finished, I need that. @Lu_

Comment: no it should not be executed after animation, there is nothing about animation in `evaluatePolicy` block

Comment: okay!But now, how to make it executed after animation finished, is there any way to approach this excepting to delay uncertain seconds? @Lu_